# ReactJS + Redux: Why getting 'POST' net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED?

Tags: json, rest, redux, reactjs

I am following https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/ at the moment, and I pretty much did the same, yet I am still getting the following error:

[image]

Is http://localhost:3001/sessions/create down? If not, what may be the cause of the error?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

I set up my Express to port 3000 as well, just like how it is shown in the tutorial and used the same API url.

[image]

Comment: looks like the server (api) you are using is not running.

Comment: @anoop by `sever (api) you are using`, do you mean  http://localhost:3001/sessions/create ? So does that mean the server is down? Because auth0 is the one providing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue could be because you are not setting a base URL in the API calls.

For example, if you are using Auth0 as a service, then API URL in requests must be as below,

```
axios.post('https://your.auth0.url/sessions/create', data);
```

(Assuming that you are using `axios`)

I suppose the current configuration is as below,

```
axios.post('/sessions/create', data);
```

and it takes the relative URL and it will be from the app serving the rendering of base page, in your case that is `localhost:3001`

It is advised to keep the base url (`http://auth0.your.url`) as an environment variable and can be supplied while running the app.

If you are using webpack take a look at Webpack define plugin also.

Comment: Please take a look at the Edit in the original post. I provided what the tutorial suggested. I did exactly the same and I set up my Express to port 3000 as well, just like how it is shown in the tutorial. So in my case, what should the URL be or what should I try out to fix the issue first? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In that blog it is suggesting you to clone and run the server app from this location `https://github.com/auth0-blog/nodejs-jwt-authentication-sample` are you doing that?

Comment: Yes I did and got it to work but in the `response.text()` it returns `user` as an error message and `user.id_token` as undefined. But when `reponse.json()`, it returns `user.message` as undefined but `user.id_token` returns correctly. What may be the issue? Thank you anoop!

Comment: Did you add the Auth0 tokens? I just cloned it and done the same steps as they suggested it is working for me.

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify on adding Auth0 tokens? Also `{response => response.json()` does return undefined for `user.message`. But when it is changed to `{response => response.text()}`, it returns the message properly but now `user.id_token` becomes undefined...